# Tensorflow batch training of single dimension numpy array without converting it into multiple dimension numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, batch-processing

I have some confusion over numpy array to tensor....

My code:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes
import numpy as np
import random

n = 2500
y = np.zeros((n), dtype = np.int32)

for i in range(n):
    y[i] = random.randint(0,1)

print "Before Batch Training:"
print "len(y):" , len(y)
print "y: " , y
print "y[9]: " , y[9]

batch_size = 10
num_preprocess_threads = 1
min_queue_examples = 256

y_batch = tf.train.batch([y], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=num_preprocess_threads, capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)

print "After Batch Training:"
print "y_batch:" , y_batch
print "y_batch[9]: " , y_batch[9]

with tf.Session() as sess:

    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    y_proccessed = sess.run(y_batch)

    print "After Session Run:"
    print "y_proccessed:" , y_proccessed
    print "y_proccessed[9]: " , y_proccessed[9]
    print "y_proccessed[0][9]: " , y_proccessed[0][9]
    print "y_proccessed[1][9]: " , y_proccessed[1][9]
    print "y_proccessed[2][9]: " , y_proccessed[2][9]
    print "y_proccessed[3][9]: " , y_proccessed[3][9]
    print "y_proccessed[4][9]: " , y_proccessed[4][9]
    print "y_proccessed[5][9]: " , y_proccessed[5][9]

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)

sess.close()
```

Result after execution:

```
Before Batch Training:
len(y): 2500
y:  [0 0 1 ..., 1 1 1]
y[9]:  1
After Batch Training:
y_batch: Tensor("batch:0", shape=(?, 2500), dtype=int32)
y_batch[9]:  Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(2500,), dtype=int32)
After Session Run:
y_proccessed: [[0 0 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 ..., 
 [0 0 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 ..., 1 1 1]]
y_proccessed[9]:  [0 0 1 ..., 1 1 1]
y_proccessed[0][9]:  1
y_proccessed[1][9]:  1
y_proccessed[2][9]:  1
y_proccessed[3][9]:  1
y_proccessed[4][9]:  1
y_proccessed[5][9]:  1
```

My confusion goes where y_proccessed[9] suppose to generate result of '1' like y[9], instead it generate [0 0 1 ..., 1 1 1]?

On the other hand, if you look at y_proccessed which produce

```
    [[0 0 1 ..., 1 1 1]
     [0 0 1 ..., 1 1 1]
     [0 0 1 ..., 1 1 1]
     ..., 
     [0 0 1 ..., 1 1 1]
     [0 0 1 ..., 1 1 1]
     [0 0 1 ..., 1 1 1]]
```

it generate the same redundant first 10 array, which it suppose to loop over to other 10 subsequence array for another batch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to fix it:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes
import numpy as np
import random

n = 2500
y = np.zeros((n), dtype = np.int32)

for i in range(n):
    y[i] = random.randint(0,1)

print "Before Batch Training:"
print "len(y):" , len(y)
print "y: " , y
print "y[9]: " , y[9]

batch_size = 10
num_preprocess_threads = 1
min_queue_examples = 256

#adding enqueue_many=True into the tf.train.batch
y_batch = tf.train.batch([y], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=num_preprocess_threads, capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size, enqueue_many=True, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)

print "After Batch Training:"
print "y_batch:" , y_batch
print "y_batch[9]: " , y_batch[9]

with tf.Session() as sess:

    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    y_proccessed = sess.run(y_batch)

    print "After Session Run:"
    print "y_proccessed:" , y_proccessed
    print "y_proccessed[9]: " , y_proccessed[9]
    print "y_proccessed[0][9]: " , y_proccessed[0][9]
    print "y_proccessed[1][9]: " , y_proccessed[1][9]
    print "y_proccessed[2][9]: " , y_proccessed[2][9]
    print "y_proccessed[3][9]: " , y_proccessed[3][9]
    print "y_proccessed[4][9]: " , y_proccessed[4][9]
    print "y_proccessed[5][9]: " , y_proccessed[5][9]

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)

sess.close()
```

I leave some additional resource for reference purpose:

[Passing a numpy array to a tensorflow Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068259/passing-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensorflow-queue)

http://ischlag.github.io/2016/11/07/tensorflow-input-pipeline-for-large-datasets/

[How to handle different queue batch size and feed value batch size in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105763/how-to-handle-different-queue-batch-size-and-feed-value-batch-size-in-tensorflow)

https://github.com/dennybritz/tf-rnn/blob/master/sequence_example.ipynb

by the way, if anyone got any better solution please post it.

Thanks